# Python Selenium - Looping through child elements

Tags: python, selenium, loops, element

[image]

How do I loop through the elements of "ctbdy" and check if "bl_name bln_end" is "Materials"?

Comment: `link = [div.p for div in 
        soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'ctbdy'})]` will get you `p` tags from there you can get `span.text`

Comment: What do you wanna do if it's materials?

Answer (score 0):

In case all span element has the same class name. Get the list of element span. Then using loop to check span text each by each.

```
list_span_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='ctbdy']/p/span[@class='bl_name bln_end']")
for element in list_span_elements:
    if (element.text == "Materials"):
        print("Find element with Materials")
```